# get tag name using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements which I got `els = $('#' + elements + ' *').get();`. Now I want to get tagNames of these elements and put them in separate array. **How can I get tag name from `els`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.tagName`, which is a property of `HTMLElement`:

```
var tagNames = []; // Array of tag names
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
   tagNames.push(els[i].tagName); 
}
```

`tagName` gives you the tag name in caps. You can convert it to small case by using `.toLowerCase()` on `.tagName` to get lower cased tag names.

---

**Note :**

As an alternative to `tagName`, you could also use `nodeName`. For tags, values of `tagName` and `nodeName` are identical!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
els = $('#' + elements + ' *').map(function(){
    return this.nodeName;
}).get();

console.log(els);
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2p6s/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use .get() method. just `$(selector)[0].nodeName` like this:

```
var tags = [];
for (i in els){
    tags.push(els[i].nodeName);
}
```